# Why is the wave function $\Psi$ a function of two variables, $x$ and $t$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, time-evolution

I'm working through David Griffith's book "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics," and I'm wondering why $\Psi$ is a function of two variables, $x$ and $t$. Whenever there is a graph of the wave function, it looks like it is only a function of one variable, $x$. Or is that just a snaphot at some fixed time $t$? Maybe the wave is floating around and changing it's shape as a function of $t$?

Comment: You are correct, the diagrams in Griffiths are a snapshot at fixed $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with your guess: the wave function (in the so called [Schrödinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture)) has a value for each position of space at each instant of time, and what you see when the graph shows it only as a function of space is a *snapshot* at a fixed value of $t$.

Nevertheless,  we are often interested in time independent problems. In these cases, the snapshot is more than enough, since the time dependence consists on a phase that multiplies the part of the wavefunction that does depend on the space coordinate $\Psi(t,x)=\exp(-i Et/\hbar)\phi(x)$.